# Laravel angularJS CORS using barryvdh/laravel-cors not working on IIS

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, cors, iis-8.5

I have problem with cross domain request to an API hosted on IIS.

I am using an angularjs application to fetch data from the API, which is developed with laravel 5 using tymondesigns/jwt-auth and barryvdh/laravel-cors package for JWT and CORS.

When the API is hosted on apache angularjs app fetches data.But when hosted on IIS it gives following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The preflight request response header:

```
Request URL:http://example.com/api/authenticate
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length:0
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

My first question is why "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not set, when hosted on IIS. Is there any special setting to enable CORS on IIS.

So then I added following lines to web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />   
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Request-With" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Now it give following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/authenticate. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The preflight request response header:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

The actual request response header:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkpwNnU2mTnc9PSIsInam9jTFpxb0ptak1IMmFsQ3ZZhbMTM5ZTMzMjgyZWIyNCJ9; expires=Thu, 27-Aug-2015 12:52:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.0
```

So Why "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is repeating" on actual request response header.

Is it secure to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for this issue is to:

- Install the CORS Module in IIS and
- Configure CORS in web.config file

[IIS CORS module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference)